# New row for horizontal unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to build a calendar in javascript which displays 5 weeks from any given date.

I have generated an unordered list with 35 days in it. Is there any way to get css to do a metaphorical`<br>` after every 7th item, so that the weeks stack up on top of each other. I have been looking at nth-child but haven't found how to make it create a new row.

Yes, this can be done with a simple javascript loop but I'd prefer a CSS solution.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: CSS is for styling elements, not for creating them

Comment: Calendars are tabular data.  Now if only there was markup for representing tabular data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}
li:nth-child(7n + 1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRZLT/).